# maven-enforcer rule not being inherited

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I defined the enforcer plugin within my parent pom like so:

```
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <rules>
                <dependencyConvergence />
            </rules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

in the child pom it is simply under

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

running `enforcer:enforce` works in the parent pom itself (as expected). I clean installed the child pom and then ran the same command, but I was met with:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.2.1:enforce (default-cli) on project my-project: No rules are configured.
```

I can't figure out why the rule is being ignored or not inherited? The plugin seems to be inherited properly but not the rule?

Comment: if you only execute enforcer by cli try to remove from child enforcer definition it contains nothing new - everything is in parent